# jQuery with ACF thinking it has class when it doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I'm having? I am trying to add a class of `col_last` to the last column of my row but don't do it if there is a column with `span_12`.

The code I have used is:

```
$(function(){

$('.section-image').addClass(function(){
return ["none", "span_12", "span_6", "span_4", "span_3"]
   [$(this).parent().children('.section-image').length];
 });

if(!$('.section').children('.section-image').hasClass('span_12')){
  $('.section-image').last().addClass('col_last');
} 

});
```

However when I put if section does not have class span_12 nothing happens. It works when I put if has class `span_3` or `span_6` etc. But not if I put, does not have 12.

All I can think of is that jQuery is thinking it has a class of `span_12` even though nothing is showing it.

I am trying to create each row dynamically by using a ACF repeater field which is why I think jQuery believes it has the class of 12.

If any one could provide someone advice on how to stop jQuery thinking this, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks to everyone for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

$('.section-image').addClass(function(){
return ["none", "span_12", "span_6", "span_4", "span_3"]
   [$(this).parent().children('.section-image').length];
 });

if(!$('.section').children('.section-image').hasClass('span_12')){
  $('.section-image:last-child').addClass('col_last');
} 

});
```

Or you could go down this route:

```
$(function(){

$('.section-image').addClass(function(){
return ["none", "span_12", "span_6", "span_4", "span_3"]
   [$(this).parent().children('.section-image').length];
 });

if($('.section').children('.section-image')!.is($('.span_12'))){
  $('.section-image:last-child').addClass('col_last');
} 

});
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the reply! I'm afraid these didn't work. When complying them with CodeKit I got lots of errors.

Comment: Fine then, be that way.